# Broken ngModel on Radio buttons with an ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4ntAj2fIIpexKjkCvlD?p=preview

I'm trying to build a form component which allows the user to create multiple instances of a certain data field, but populate them from the same set of inputs.

I'm creating a radio button for each of the items within the set, using `ng-repeat` then each radio button has its value set to the `$index` from the repeat. The radio buttons are modelled on `$scope.selectedItem`, which is used to point the inputs to the right item.

For some reason, however, `selectedItem` never changes, even though the selected state of the radio buttons do.

I tried a similar thing with static radio buttons and it worked fine, which leads me to believe that there is a problem with `ng-model` within `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `ngModel` for each button. Then, since each iteration of `ngRepeat` creates a new isolate scope, you have two ways to reference your variable in the parent controller:

1. change `selectedItem` to an object. this works because objects are passed by reference in JS, while passing a primitive like you have doesn't work with two-way binding.
2. add `$parent.selectedItem`, which references the scope variable `selectedItem` in the controller.

In any case, you need `ngModel` for each button.

**First option:**

```
<input type='radio' 
       name='select' 
       id='{{$index}}' 
       ng-value='$index' 
       ng-model='$parent.selectedItem'/>
```

[Plunker Using `$parent`](http://plnkr.co/edit/pTOXFAt2V2DADwZAJ9eL?p=preview)

**Second option:**

JS:

```
$scope.selectedItem = {id: -1};
```

HTML:

```
<input type='radio' 
       name='select' 
       id='{{$index}}' 
       ng-value='$index' 
       ng-model='selectedItem.id'/>
```

(as well as change anywhere else you reference `selectedItem` to `selectedItem.id`)

[Plunker Using an object for `selectedItem`](http://plnkr.co/edit/ua7m6HjRM87vbYyU7maw?p=preview)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I had slightly misunderstood how isolate scopes worked. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope helped clear it up.